# how to call one api to another api in laravel using wamp server?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

in Web.php

Route::get('/apiforsales', [LeadController::class, 'apiforsales']); //this working fine.

Route::get('/apicheck', [LeadController::class,'apicheck123']);

LeadController.php

```
public function apiforsales(Request $req)
{
 $results = DB::select( DB::raw(" select id,name,implement,lead_type,number,district,state FROM comman_datas where state = '$req->state' and district= '$req->district' and status = '0'  "));   
 return $results;
}

public function apicheck123(Request $req)
{
    $response = Http::get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/apiforsales?state=".$req->state."&district=".$req->district);
    $jsondata= $response->getBody();
    $data =json_decode($jsondata, true);
    return $data;
}
```

In postman calling a api

http://127.0.0.1:8000/apiforsales?state=Karnataka&district=Bengaluru  ..///working fine.

http://127.0.0.1:8000/apicheck?state=Karnataka&district=Bengaluru  ..///it will loading to much time not giving a exact cause of

Comment: What is the point of the apicheck endpoint? Use functions to call subroutines from your own app, not http requests. This probably times out because the server you used (127.0.0.1:8000) is not accessible from the context in which the app is running.

Comment: Your apiforsales endpoint is also vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/10977). Use either the Eloquent ORM which comes standard with Laravel, or prepared statements support on the DB::select method.

Comment: ok brooo...thank u  for your suggestion i take your point.